# Could you please explain the following code to an easier format? I'm not getting the code properly

Tags: python, split

`hashes = (line.split(':') for line in hashes.text.splitlines())
    for h,count in hashes:
        if h==hash_to_check:
            return count`

Can you explain the code?

Comment: If your problem is the 1st line, look up [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have a string containing multiple lines: `hashes.text = 'foo:1\nbar:2\n'`. The first line transforms that into `(['foo', '1'], ['bar', '2'])`. The second line loops over that list of lists and the loop body returns the second element of the inner list where the first element of the inner list matches `hash_to_check`. So if `hash_to_check = 'foo'`, then it would return `'1'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
hashes = []

for line in hashes.text.splitlines():
    hashes.append(line.split(':'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

hashes_text = f"""
({random.getrandbits(128)}: 1 \n
{random.getrandbits(128)}: 2 \n
"""

hash_to_check = random.getrandbits(128)

hashes = (line.split(':') for line in hashes_text.splitlines())
for h, count in hashes:
    if h==hash_to_check:
        print(count)
```